# Remove Introductory banner for signed in accounts over a certain age?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-accounts, homepage

I noticed today that this banner appeared again on my front-page:
[image]

I recall having removed the banner several times after I understood how the site works many moons ago, yet it keeps on reappearing for some reason.

So I would like to propose, if this isn't just a glitch, to modify the banner logic to remove this for signed in accounts that have passed a certain age.

Presumably, such account holders will know how the site works after such a period and won't need the reminder, though if need be, an additional message could notify that removing the banner would be permanent, before proceeding.

Comment: I think that if you have x amount of rep or more you can dismiss that banner instead of age.

Answer (score 7):

You could have an account that's ten years old at that point and have never done anything on the site itself, so I disagree with age being a factor here.

I *think* the appearance of the banner is tied to rep thresholds; if you've done at least something on this site then you won't see it anymore.  Otherwise, the system is going to assume that you're still new here and need a refresher on how the place works.

Comment: It does seem better to do it that way, but that might be the problem since it so obvious, as the devs seem not to have done the obvious and straightforward thing. Perhaps they don't want to introduce a new feature with account rep, or it's complex to adjust the backend code, etc.

Comment: I just checked and the hero banner was shown to me, so at least it's not tied to the rep :) The appearance is handled by the cookie named "hero" which has 1-year expiry though.